# 'choco' not recognized, but chocolatey is installed

Tags: powershell, installation, chocolatey

Tried to install chocolatey on my windows machine, got back some errors that I, unfortunately, don't have. When I tried the installation process again, I got back an error that chocolatey was already installed. So I tried to execute a choco command but it was not recognized:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
WARNING: Files from a previous installation of Chocolatey were found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'.
WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue.
For security reasons, this script will not overwrite existing installations.

Please use choco upgrade chocolatey to handle upgrades of Chocolatey itself.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> choco upgrade chocolatey
choco : The term 'choco' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ choco upgrade chocolatey
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (choco:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is it in your PATH?

Comment: Try `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

The important part in the output that you have shown is this part...

> WARNING: Files from a previous installation of Chocolatey were found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'.
>
> WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue.
> For security reasons, this script will not overwrite existing installations.

During installation, Chocolatey modifies the permissions on the installation folder for security purposes. It can't do this effectively if the installation folder already exists, therefore the installation will halt and not continue.

If Chocolatey is indeed *not* installed, and the suggestion from @mklement0 didn't help, then the suggestion would be to delete the `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey` folder, and then run the installation script again.

You mentioned that during the original installation attempt that there were errors, but you also didn't mention what those errors were.  Can you provide more information about what you were seeing, and perhaps we can provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the chocolatey from `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey` and try again. That will work !

Comment: What does this add to the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

I got this and found that my PATH environment variable was being truncated. I created a new environment variable NEWPATH, cut and pasted half of the PATH variable to it, then added %NEWPATH% to the PATH variable.

Then I made sure that "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey" was added to the PATH as well.